# Pass Parameters between views-MVC-3-Not TempData Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a drop down in one view, I have to use the selected value of this drop down in other view.

I do not want to use Tempdata Approach as it is not best practice.

Is there any better approach for this.

Please give the best practice solution.

Thank you
Hari

Comment: Can you give us a better description of how the two views are related? Are they both partial views in a container view? Are they separated by more than one HTTP request?

Comment: They are totally different Views. One View Name Is AddAbsence and Other ViewName is AmendAbsence.

Comment: When you post the value from the first drop down, do you render the next view (the one requiring the first drop down value) from that controller action?

Comment: yes , you are right. Based on the first view drop down value, I have to get the second view(filtered) by selected value of first  dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I can modify this is you provide me with a larger picture (read: more code) of what's already in your views

First view (your `List<SelectListItem>` will probably differ)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Step2", "Silly")) {
    @Html.DropDownList("NameOfDropDown", new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "Label 1",
            Value = "1"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = "Label 2",
            Value = "2"
        }
    })
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public class SillyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step2(string NameOfDropDown)
    {
        // if the only value being passed is a string, you'll need
        // to wrap it in something like a view model class
        return View(new Step2ViewModel() { MyValue = NameOfDropDown });
    }
}

public class Step2ViewModel()
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

And in the second view, Step2.cshtml (assuming Razor)

```
@model Yournamespace.Step2ViewModel

<div>@Model.MyValue</div>
```